# move_base Get plan not working for real time data?

Tags: ros, navigation, move-base, p3dx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using P3dx bot and want to get a plan using move_base Get Plan service, so when I use data like tf and scan messages directly from robot I get the following warning :

```
[ WARN] [1359052907.140636231]: Could not get robot pose, cancelling reconfiguration
[ WARN] [1359052908.140937352]: Costmap2DROS transform timeout. Current time: 1359052908.1409, global_pose stamp: 1359052907.5267, tolerance: 0.2000
```

and planning fails, but when i store the data in bag file and then run the code it works fine.
Can anyone please help..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53305/move_base-get-plan-not-working-for-real-time-data???/) by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1610 on 2013-01-24

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a typical problem in the navigation stack if you use a distributed navigation architecture. The time delays are a problem.

Your global costmap has a parameter "/transform_tolerance (double, default: 0.2)"
What that means? If your sensor data or your odometry data is too old they are not reliable information to build a costmap. Remember that a costmap is like a mapping method (but not slam). A very high cumulated odometry error could end up in an absolutley incoherent costmap.

In any case try to increase the transform_tolerance parameter and after that told us your results please!

---

Originally posted by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) with karma: 2982 on 2013-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks a lot, the problem seems to be resolved. I had to increase the value from 0.2 to 1.5. The value is written in costmap_common_params.yaml.

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-01-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2